# Solana wallet in Flutter

Tags: typescript, flutter, dart, solana

I want to connect to any Solana wallet like Phantom, Sollet, TrustWallet, etc. but there seems to be no package to integrate.

I tried-

1. I tried Dart JS interop for Phantom but that is also not working fine.

Maybe Solana wallet adapter transpilation from Typescript to Dart could lead to any solution.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why specifically you want to do with solana ? let me know

Comment: I was taking part in solana ignition hackathon &    chose flutter for web app. Pub also contains Solana package to interact with json rpc api but there seems to be no resources to integrate phantom or other wallet & sign transaction.

Comment: maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69777908/how-to-connect-a-phantom-wallet-to-my-flutter-web-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a (crude) working piece of code

// web/index.html

```
<script src="../lib/wallet.js" />
```

// wallet.js

```
class ClientWallet {

    constructor() {
        this.pubKey = '';
    }

    async connect() {
        const resp = await window.solana.connect();
        this.pubKey = resp.publicKey.toString();
    }

    address() {
        return this.pubKey;
    }

    disconnect() {
        window.solana.disconnect();
    }
}

var walletModule = { ClientWallet: ClientWallet };
```

// main.dart

```
import 'package:js/js.dart';
import 'package:js/js_util.dart';

@JS('walletModule.ClientWallet')
class ClientWallet {
  external Future<void> connect();
  external void disconnect();
  external String get pubKey;
}

Future<void> connectWallet() async {
  ClientWallet wallet = ClientWallet();
  await promiseToFuture(wallet.connect());
}
```

And then for connecting simply call connectWallet(). This works for me for the Phantom wallet.

EDIT: To accomplish this I went to the [docs for connecting a Phantom wallet](https://docs.phantom.app/integrating/establishing-a-connection). I also had to use [Dart-JS interop](https://pub.dev/packages/js) to make it work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Tyler2P I edited the comment and added the docs for Phantom the Dart-JS interop

Comment: @user3889291 thanks, too noticed my interop code was working fine. The problem was with the debug environment as it doesn't allow external extensions.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this at the moment, unless there exists an additional external package.  Your best bet may be to add the wallet bindings to the community Dart package: https://github.com/cryptoplease/cryptoplease-dart

Answer (score 0):

You can use my package [flutter_phantom](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_phantom)

this is signAndSendTransaction example

```
Future<web3.Transaction> createTransactionTransfer() async {
   final transaction = web3.Transaction(
  feePayer: phantom.phantomWalletPublicKey,
  recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash);
 transaction.add(
   SystemProgram.transfer(
    fromPublicKey: phantom.phantomWalletPublicKey,
    toPublicKey: phantom.phantomWalletPublicKey,
    lamports: web3.solToLamports(1),
   ),
   );
return transaction;
}

 void signAndSendTransaction() async {
  try { 
   web3.Transaction transaction = await createTransactionTransfer();

   web3.Buffer transactionSerialize = transaction
    .serialize(const web3.SerializeConfig(requireAllSignatures: false));

final url = phantom.generateSignAndSendTransactionUri(
    transaction: transactionSerialize,
    redirect: "onSignAndSendTransaction");

launchUrl(
  url,
  mode: LaunchMode.externalNonBrowserApplication,
);
 } catch (e) {
 print(e)
  }
 }
```

full example of how to use this package [flutter_phantom-demo](https://github.com/NavidHosseini/flutter_phantom-demo)